# Is There A Way To Access A Separate Local Database From Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress plugin that requires connecting to a separate database that is local to the wordpress database.

Is there a way to use wpdb to connect to a different local database?

Does wordpress have a function that returns the database username and password so I dont have to hardcode the user name and password into my plugin?

I tried the following

```
$years = $this->wpdb->get_results(
            $this->wpdb->prepare("SELECT *
FROM `YearsDatabase.years` , ""),
            ARRAY_A
        );
        return $years;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes no maybe, well yes. The plugin itself would set up its own database connection with its own user so you would have concurrent connections when that plugin runs.

However, I would be wondering why a plugin needs a seperate database when it could just prefix the tables it creates with a unique identifier to avoid clashes and simply just use the existing database connection.

Besides that you I think you actually have an error in your sql query try

```
`YearsDatabase`.`years`
```